# Proof relating to sum of Lebesgue integrable functions

Tags: metric-spaces, lebesgue-integral, lebesgue-measure

I've been asked to find the proof for the following proposition:

Let $(f_{n})_{n \geq1}$ be a sequence of Lebesgue measure functions defined on a Lebesgue measurable set $A$ with values in either $R$ or $C$ such that $\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty}\int_{A}|f_{n}(x)|dx < \infty$. Then let the series defined by $f(x) = \sum_{n = 1}^{\infty}f_{n}(x)$ be absolutely convergent almost everywhere for $x \in A, f \in L^{1}(A)$. Prove that:
$$
\int_{A}f(x)dx = \sum_{n = 1}^{\infty}\int_{A}f_{n}(x)dx
$$

I'm not really sure how to go about solving this problem and appreciate the help in solving it. Many thanks in advance!

Comment: This is false. You need to remove the absolute values in the conclusion. As a hint: what very well-known measure theoretic result allows you to interchange integrals and limits (series are limits of sums)?

Comment: Yep that was my mistake and I've changed that now. I know using the monotone and dominated convergence theorem will help here but I'm just not sure how to make my argument combining these two theorems.

Answer (score 0):

This is for $\int f_1 + \int f_2 = \int (f_1 + f_2)$ case, the extension follows naturally.

For any function $f_1$ there exists simple function
$\phi_n$ with $0 \leq \phi_n \leq f_1$ such that
$\phi_1 \leq \phi_2 \leq \cdots$ and
$\phi_x(x) \underset{n \to \infty}{\to} f_1(x)$ for all x.

Similarly, there exists $\psi_n$ such that $0 \leq \psi_n \leq f_2$
with $\psi_1 \leq \psi_2 \leq \cdots$ and $\psi_n(x) \to f_2(x)$.

Now, $\phi_n + \psi_n$ is simple, and increasing in n so
$\phi_n(x) + \psi_n(x) \to f_1(x) + f_2(x)$.

$$
\begin{aligned}
\int(f_1 + f_2) &\underset{MCT}{=} \lim_{n \to \infty} \int (\phi_n + \psi_n))\\
&= \lim_{n \to \infty} \int \phi_n  + \lim_{n \to \infty} \int \psi_n\\
&\underset{MCT}{\longrightarrow} \int f_1 + \int f_2
\end{aligned}
$$